# How can I delete the content of a folder but not the folder itself?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

Let say I have a folder on my Desktop, inside this folder are files and other folders which they are so many and large and may take some sec to delete all of them, I want get notified when my delete action is finished then I can run next line of code `echo "Delete finished!"` in a shell. I am using this code right now, but the printing happens before the delete finish and makes issue.

**My goal is just making my folder empty. And keeping Empty folder**

```
echo "Starting to Delete!"
cd Desktop
rm -rf TestFolder
mkdir TestFolder
echo "Delete finished!"
```

*I am new in terminal or bash please bear with. thanks*

Comment: It's often faster to delete the whole folder and then to recreate it, empty, than to delete each file inside.

Comment: I also thought that would be the best way, and code like that, but some how I am feeling that mkdir runs before rm finish its job.

Comment: I don't think that this is the case.  As far as I am aware, `rm` is [synchronous](https://www.koyeb.com/blog/introduction-to-synchronous-and-asynchronous-processing).

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584919/108618

Comment: foreground threads in bash are synchronous, so each line completes its tasks before the next line runs. It is possible that the disk still has pending deferred writes, but those will be handled transactionally, such that other tasks will not be impacted by the disks asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Do we have some sort of completion handler for bash or terminal, in that way that I get call back from `rm` for safer coding and then run `mkdir` with small delay?

Comment: If what @FrankThomas says is true (thanks Frank!).. try running the `sync -f` command between the other commands to be sure that pending writes are handled and flush the disk.  I myself have never needed this command to do what you are trying to do but it can't hurt :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, Commands in a sh-based shell script will run synchronously, with the command being executed sequentially, such that each command completes before the next is started.

The primary exception to this is when the command is explicitly started in, or moved to "the background", generally by placing an `&` at then end of the invocation. Commands running in the background are detached from the shell, and the shell can't tell when they exit, so if a task in the middle of a script is run in the background, then the script will begin execution, and hang up, proceeding on to the next command.

In your case, there are likely components to your system that are not entirely done processing your `rm` (in particular the hard disk itself), but rest assured, the filesystem API is written to ensure that the next command won't notice any cleanup related to deferred writes.

you can rest assured that the command to delete the files has completed by the time the `mkdir` command runs. the disk may still be active, but the system has already done its job.

also, to respond to your title, to delete a directories contents, but not the directory, use `rm -rf /path/to/dir/*`

Comment: I am not native english speaker but synchronously means to me = All together, so it means my code for delete and create the folder happens at same time together?

Comment: no, that's not what it means when you are talking about programing. it means that each line executes in order, and once complete, proceeds to the next line. think of the line `x = 2-1`. synchronously means that by the time this line is done, x will be set with the value 1. its synchrnous because its "in synch" with the rest of the code execution.  the opposite of synchronous code is `asynchronous`  code, which does not execute relative to the rest of the code. for async code, you don't know how long it will take, so the program kicks it off, and then proceeds to the next line.

Comment: what you describe where it all happens at once, is called "concurrent" (or sometimes "parallel") in programming. if all the lines executed at the same time, that would be concurrent. synchronous just means that relative to the rest of the execution, each line executes, and then the next line can reference variables from the prior line, because the previous code has completed before this code starts.

Comment: Thanks for information.

Comment: so I've been thinking about the actual definition of the word synchronous, and the difficulties it has caused in our communication. you are correct, when you look the word up, it does mean "Same Time" under the most common usages. that's not what it means here, but I can understand your confusion. in this case, the easiest way to understand "synchronous execution" is to first look at Asynchronous execution, and realize that its opposite is "synchronous". from wikipedia, async can be defined as "the occurrence of events independent of the main program flow, and ways to deal with such events"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rm -r TestFolder/*`

- The asterisk represents all the files inside "TestFolder" including folders and files.
- `-r` means "remove files recursively".
- If you are new in the terminal, run `man rm` for the manual of rm, there you will find all the commands in detail.